# Log4j default placeholder value

Tags: java, log4j

I use log4j with this appender:

```
<appender name="fileAppenderRoot" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="${log.location}/logFile.log" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%c{1}] - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

If I start the server with `-Dlog.location=/path/to/logs`, log4j will log into `/path/to/logs/logFile.log` but if I specify nothing, *log4j will fail appending* to `/logFile.log`.

Is it possible to **specify a default placeholder value**?

Comment: so where do you want to place your `.log` files. what do you mean by default location here

Comment: For example, if I do not specify __log.location__ property, I want logs in /tmp/logFile.log, but if I specify it (-Dlog.location=/path/to/logs), I want logs in /path/to/logs/logFile.log.

Comment: if i understand you need to log in a absolute path right ?>

Comment: Absolute or relative, it's not really my problem. I want to change the log location, according to the system where the war is deployed.  

I just want to set a default placeholder value if none is specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. you need to provide a location to write the log file.

If you need to generate the logs in the folder where you war is deployed ,

```
<param name="file" value="../logs/logFile.log" />
```

will create `logfile` in the folder where you have deployed

[Read more here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11159_01/books/install/eBilling_Install_GetStarted6.html)

Comment: The feature needed is to provide a default value to the 'log.location' property not to set the log location statically.

Comment: Well, removed some text in my comment. You are right that his last comment perhaps changes the whole question. As it contradicts with the question and other comments I think we should let @Calfater decide what s/he needs.

Comment: so my answer is generic . log file would be created independent of the deployment path .

Comment: But in the same relative location. I think that even if Calfater will be OK with your answer the original question as I understand it is still valid and might be useful

Comment: Ok what do you expect from the question . there are some paths such as `{CATALINA_HOME}`,`{USER.APPROOT}` . They take paths during runtime

Comment: I simply expect this feature: be able to specify as a system property or env variable as a replacement for a '${log.location}' (in this case) token and if not supplied, take a default value that is configured somewhere else. More specifically, something equivalent to this: <param name="file" value="${log.location}/logFile.log" default-value="/tmp/logFile.log" />

Comment: The answer of san krish seems good because he says "No". Thanks @shlomi33 to rewrite more clearly my expectations ;)

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but I find a better solution is to use a whole server-specific log4j configuration file. This allows customization of specific logger levels, etc. on a per-server basis.

Both WebLogic and GlassFish (and probably other servers) provide mechanisms to place extra files on the classpath for one specific application. You can use these mechanisms to override a default `log4j.xml` baked into the WAR. WebLogic provides [File Loading Overrides](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/11119/wls/DEPGD/config.htm#DEPGD188) and GlassFish [Application-Specific Class Loading](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/gatej/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is add the default value in the code

```
private static void configureLogger() {
    String logLocation = System.getProperty("log.location");
    if (logLocation == null) {
        System.setProperty("log.location", "/path/to/logs");
    }

    // if a logger is needed in the current class, create it after 

    log = Logger.getLogger(SomeClass.class);
}
```

You need to add this code before all code that uses the logger. It can be added in a startup servlet, for example. Please, don't create a logger in the usual way, with a static field initializer, in such servlet.